# Can such PDEs effectively be solved as ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following partial differential equation:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial~f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)^2-f(x,y)=0~.
$$

I have the following doubt, given that only one partial derivative is present can this equation be, somehow, turned into an ODE? My train of thought was: for a specific value o f $y$, the above equation would be for all means and purposes an ode and my guess is that the dependence in $y$ would be given by the initial condition $f(0,y)=g(y)$ for some function $g(y)$. Does this make sense? If so, would this be the case for every PDE with partial derivatives with respect to only one variable?

Comment: Yes, it's a family of ODEs, indexed by $y$, so formally you can treat them as ODEs. However, in your case the ODE is really $u' = \sqrt{u}$ (up to choice of sign), which does not have unique solutions (the Lipschitz condition fails in Picard's theorem).

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation.